# c++ odeint output "not a number"

Tags: c++, nan, odeint

I am working with the c++ boost/odeint to integrate chemical reaction networks. Everything works fine except when I eliminate some of the reactions. Then there are sometimes -nan's in the output. here is a small portion of that output. first column is the time and the others are concentrations of the species.

```
0.0         2.8701  3.4354  3.48348 4.30509         5.43538 5.35687 2.9138  5.31905 3.51382
0.0268472   -nan    2.93435 -nan    -nan            -nan    -nan    2.9138  -nan    -nan
0.0695729   -nan    2.28324 -nan    -nan            -nan    -nan    2.9138  -nan    -nan
0.112299    -nan    1.77661 -nan    -nan            -nan    -nan    2.9138  -nan    -nan
0.155024    -nan    1.3824  -nan    -nan            -nan    -nan    2.9138  -nan    -nan
0.19939     -nan    1.06535 -nan    -nan            -nan    -nan    2.9138  -nan    -nan
```

The second species only depends on itself and the 7th species is constant. 

So my question is: When does odeint give a -nan as output? Maybe there is a 0/0 devision somewhere, but all equations contain only products e.g.

dxdt[5] = - c[2] * x[5] + c[3] * x[9] * x[3];

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: Can you give more informations about your setup, for example which stepper do you use. For example the runge_kutta steppers shouldn't give any NaNs, (except for fixed points at infintiy :) ).

Comment: for this example I just used the simple integration function integrate( system , x0 , t0 , t1 , dt ). The docs say it uses a "dense output stepper based on runge_kutta_dopri5".

Comment: There are different possibilities for the NaNs. But they should not occur if you use a runge_kutta4 stepper, which does not mean that RK4 is superior to dopri5. Can you try to integrate your system with runge_kutta4, like integrate_const( runge_kutta4< state_type >() , system , x0 , t0 , t1 , dt ); Maybe the r.h.s. of your ODE produces to large values, that the system will go to infinity very fast.

Comment: With runge_kutta4 the first values are like 1.e+87 and then nan. But as I said in my own answer below the problem was solved by reducing the initial step size dt. Even though I am still surprised at the ODE producing such high values. But thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read somewhere else that the step size can be a problem. So I just reduced the initial step size dt by a factor 10 and now it is working. Maybe the initial slope was to large for some of the species.
Thanks for the replies!

Why is it that you struggle days with the answer and as soon as you ask it on stackoverflow you find it yourself? :D

Comment: I have a similar problem, but wasn't able to resolve it. How do you change the initial (or maximum and minimum) step size for an adaptive stepper?

Answer (score 3):

Well there are several possible reasons for NaN:

- Division by zero `x/0`
- Dividing +- Infinity with itself `Infinity / Infinity`
- Multiplication  `0 × (+- Infinity)`
- Adding / subtracting Infinity to itself (e.g. `Infinity - Infinity`)
- `Any operation with NaN` will also result in NaN

So most likely, something of the mentioned above happens in your code. A NaN in IEEE 754 is in the form where all exponent bit = 1, yet the mantissa bits and not. The leading bit indicates + or - NaN.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see how any species can get Infinity cause all species together have a value of about 10. But I'll contine check the system once more.

Comment: @Andro47 Division _of Infinity_ by +-Infinity results in NaN. I case of division of some finite number by +-Infinity you will get +-0.0, respectively.

Comment: @Archie You are right, I has that thought process but expressed myself inaccurately. Edited.